# Where can I find AuthComponent.php?

Tags: cakephp

I want to use AuthComponent but I found out I don't have this file under Controller/Component. Where can I get this php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AuthComponent is part of the cakePHP core libraries, you won't find it under your app folder. Depending on the cakePHP version you are using, the location could be different. In cakePHP 2.0, you can find the file at app_root/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php.

You don't need to touch any core cakePHP files though. If you want to use the AuthComponent, just add it to you AppController like this:

```
public $components = array('Auth');
```